# Retrieve Thread Name In IOS of non-current thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, multithreading

[image: Thread name Example: 'com.apple.coremedia.player.async']

How do you retrieve the "name" of a thread ?

(see picture of xcode with app paused, where, what I am calling the "name" is highlighted in yellow, "com.apple.coremedia.player.async"... I can retrieve the running threads, and have tried the following, with no luck

```
mach_msg_type_number_t count, i;
thread_act_array_t list;

task_threads(mach_task_self(), &list, &count);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (list[i] == mach_thread_self()) continue;

    char theName[16];

    memset(theName, 0x00, sizeof(theName));
    pthread_getname_np(list[i], theName);
    printf("The thread name is %s.\n", theName);

}
```

NOTE: I am not asking for the thread name of the current thread.. I am interested in getting the thread name from the set of running threads (see example above).. so the solution regarding [NSThread currentThread] will not work

Comment: I believe PLCrashReporter is able to do this, try checking out their page.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Print out the thread name of each of the running threads

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is simple: `task_threads` returns an array of Mach ports, not an array of `pthread_t`.  In your call to `pthread_getname_np`, you are treating a Mach port as a `pthread_t`.  But a Mach port is not a `pthread_t`.  You need to convert each to a `pthread_t` using `pthread_from_mach_thread_np`:

```
static void dumpThreads(void) {
    char name[256];
    mach_msg_type_number_t count;
    thread_act_array_t list;
    task_threads(mach_task_self(), &list, &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        pthread_t pt = pthread_from_mach_thread_np(list[i]);
        if (pt) {
            name[0] = '\0';
            int rc = pthread_getname_np(pt, name, sizeof name);
            NSLog(@"mach thread %u: getname returned %d: %s", list[i], rc, name);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"mach thread %u: no pthread found", list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output from my test program:

```
2013-03-14 03:21:45.908 hole[28315:c07] url connection complete
2013-03-14 03:21:46.787 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 3079: getname returned 0: 
2013-03-14 03:21:46.789 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 6147: getname returned 0: 
2013-03-14 03:21:46.790 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 6915: getname returned 0: 
2013-03-14 03:21:46.792 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 7683: getname returned 0: WebThread
2013-03-14 03:21:46.794 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 13059: getname returned 0: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
2013-03-14 03:21:46.796 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 16131: getname returned 0: 
2013-03-14 03:21:46.798 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 17667: getname returned 0: 
2013-03-14 03:21:46.801 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 18187: getname returned 0: com.apple.CFSocket.private
2013-03-14 03:21:46.802 hole[28315:c07] mach thread 20227: getname returned 0:
```

Comment: You sir are awesome !  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  The community thanks you for your service =)

Comment: This work fine for me if thread name was set by someone. If thread is dispatch worker thread can be good to find out name of the dispatch queue that is being executed on that thread. Project https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash has functions ksmach_getThreadName and ksmach_getThreadQueueName but they do not works for me on OSX 10.9.

Answer (score 8):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003746

`[[NSThread currentThread] name]` should do the trick, I believe.

Comment: Note that this answer will only help if OP wants only the current thread.  If OP wants all threads then this answer is not helpful.

Comment: how would you get the thread name for where you have gotten access to the thread via a list (not the current thread).. as in the example above task_threads(mach_task_self(), &list, &count);

Comment: This returns an empty string for me.

Comment: @bugloaf that is because their is no name set for your thread, you can set the name of the thread like this: `[[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"my thread"]` . Or before starting the thread set it name `[thread setName:@"custom thread"]`.